# Java - Collect, remove attributes (all extending a superclass) of a class depending on unique ID

Tags: java, java-8

Ok so here is my problem.

I have a "superclass" that I will call "Animal". Each "Animal" possesses a unique ID

```
public class Animal {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
}
```

I have several classes which extend "Animal" (Lion, Zebra, Penguin...)

```
public class Penguin extends Animal...
```

Finally, I have a class that I will call "NoahsArk" which possesses specific "Animal" attributes, such as

```
public class NoahsArk {

    private Zebra zebra;

    private Lion lion;

    private Penguin penguin;

}
```

Finally, I want to do a few things :

1. Being able to return the list of "Animals" of my "NoahsArk"
2. Being able to return the "Animal" whose ID equals a given ID (given #1, I know how to do this)
3. Being able to remove (set as null) the "Animal" whose ID equals a given ID

I know that in a such a simple case, for #1, I would just have to do something like

```
public List<Animal> getAnimals() {
    List<Animal> animals= new ArrayList<>();
    if (lion != null) {
        animals.add(lion);
    }
    ...
    return animals;
}
```

And for #2, I can simply do this

```
public Animal getAnimalById(String id) {
        return getAnimals().stream().filter(a -> a.getId().toString().equals(id)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
```

But let's assume that NoahsArk has a lot of "Animals", which are not stored in a `List<Animal>` but declared separately.

In such a case , is there an efficient way, at least in terms of written lines of code, to do things #1 and #3 ?

My first instinct, for #3, was to use the output of #1 and then set the "Animal" whose ID matches the input to null, but that just won't work.

Comment: Why don't you just store the list of animals instead of separate fields?

Comment: Even better than a list, use a map (with the id as the key). Just make sure to properly implement equals() and hashCode() in the ObjectId class.

Comment: @Olivier well I would if that was only up to me, but for our use that is made of "NoahsArk", setters and getters of ```lion```, ```penguin``` or ```zebra``` are needed

Answer (score 2):

Just because you have to provide getter and setter methods, you don't have to store each value into its own field. Being free in choosing an internal representation is what encapsulation is all about:

```
public class NoahsArk {
    private final Map<Class<? extends Animal>, Animal> stored = new HashMap<>();
    private <A extends Animal> A get(Class<A> type) {
      return type.cast(stored.get(type));
    }
    private <A extends Animal> void set(Class<A> type, A animal) {
      if(animal == null) stored.remove(type);
      else stored.put(type, animal);
    }
    public Zebra getZebra() {
      return get(Zebra.class);
    }
    public void setZebra(Zebra zebra) {
      set(Zebra.class, zebra);
    }
    public Lion getLion() {
      return get(Lion.class);
    }
    public void setLion(Lion lion) {
      set(Lion.class, lion);
    }
    public Penguin getPenguin() {
      return get(Penguin.class);
    }
    public void setPenguin(Penguin penguin) {
      set(Penguin.class, penguin);
    }
    public List<Animal> getAll() {
      return new ArrayList<>(stored.values());
    }
    public void remove(ObjectId id) {
      stored.values().removeIf(a -> a.getId().equals(id));
    }
}
```

Instead of having a map from type to animal, you could have a map from id to animal, making `remove` more efficient, at the expense of having less efficient getters and setters. Or you have both maps, making all operations fast, but having a higher memory consumption and needing more care to have both in a consistent state.

In real life, I'd ask the customer for clarification first. Shouldn't there be two of each? Otherwise, you may end up with a software fulfilling the specification literally, but still having a dissatisfied customer...

Answer (score 1):

Given the silly nature of the exercise that you have been set, I suspect that the people marking your solution would be happy with simple, easy to understand code.  Basically, like your original idea, or simpler.

It would also be possible to use Java reflection to implement the methods in parts 1 to 3 of your question.  The code would be complicated and slower.  But it would certainly be doable.  If you want to learn more, I recommend that you start with the Oracle tutorials on this subject:

- [The Java™ Tutorials: Trail: The Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

---

But would it be more efficient "in terms of lines of code"?

Lines of code is not a measure of efficiency.  Not of code performance or of programmer efficiency.  And this is not a sensible thing to optimize for.  (You shouldn't get bonus marks for fewer lines of code, IMO, unless the code is actually more maintainable.  It probably won't be in this case.)

If you actually mean programmer efficiency, it is debatable.  You are trading off the complexity of reflection against the repetitiousness of the simple version.  Taking a section of code that works on one field and then cut-and-pasting-and-modifying it for multiple fields is not hard work.  Unless you have a really large number of these fields, cut and paste may be more efficient.

A question for you to ask yourself: given what they have taught you so far, to you think they are expecting a complicated solution?  Have they taught you about reflection (yet)?  Is it even on the syllabus for your course?

---

In the real world ... you would not solve this problem this way.  You would redesign the API to be more practical.

Comment: I am not debating the fact that the length of the code is not a measure of efficiency.
I am merely curious of whether there axists a way to do the same thing using more advanced concepts, and, if possible, in fewer lines of code.

Comment: 1)  If you don't mean efficiency, don't call it efficiency!  2) Yes it is possible to use more advanced concepts.  Research "Java reflection".  Mike's answer is a start.  Whether it is fewer lines of code depends on how many fields the `NoahsArk` class has.  If you do an implementation, you will be able to work out where the break-even point is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection.

`NoahsArk.class.getDeclaredFields()` will give you all the `Field` objects in `NoahsArk`, and since the fields that we are talking about are private, you might have to do `field.setAccessible( true );` on each one of them before trying to do anything with it.

For more information, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html, but in just a few words, here is what you have at your disposal using reflection:

`field.getDeclaredAnnotations()` will give you the annotations on that field so that you can check whether it has the `@Id` annotation, or `field.getAnnotation( Id.class )` will give you the `Id` annotation or `null` if the field does not have that annotation.

`field.get( instanceOfNoahsArk )` will give you the value of a field.

`field.set( instanceOfNoahsArk, null )` will set a field to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution, based on an internal array:

```
class NoahsArk
{
    private static final int ZEBRA = 0;
    private static final int LION = 1;
    private static final int PENGUIN = 2;
    private Animal[] animals = new Animal[3];

    public Zebra getZebra()
    {
        return (Zebra)animals[ZEBRA];
    }

    public void setZebra(Zebra zebra)
    {
        animals[ZEBRA] = zebra;
    }

    public Lion getLion()
    {
        return (Lion)animals[LION];
    }

    public void setLion(Lion lion)
    {
        animals[LION] = lion;
    }

    public Penguin getPenguin()
    {
        return (Penguin)animals[PENGUIN];
    }

    public void setPenguin(Penguin penguin)
    {
        animals[PENGUIN] = penguin;
    }

    public List<Animal> getList()
    {
        ArrayList<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        for(Animal animal : animals)
        {
            if(animal!=null)
                list.add(animal);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public Animal getById(ObjectId id)
    {
        for(Animal animal : animals)
        {
            if(animal!=null && animal.getId().equals(id))
                return animal;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void removeById(ObjectId id)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<animals.length;i++)
        {
            if(animals[i]!=null && animals[i].getId().equals(id))
            {
                animals[i] = null;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```